# WSO2 IoTServer - Issue with Policies: Disallow install apps

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

I'm trying to try this functionality, but I can not make it work. My phones simply ignore it. Probe with Android 5, 6 and 7, in scenarios COPE (Android 5) and BYOD (Android 6 and 7). It's a bug?

Thanks in advance. 
Martín

Comment: I've set as device owner: org.wso2.iot.agent/org.wso2.iot.agent.services.AgentDeviceAdminReceiver

Comment: What is the brand and the model of your phone. Can you step down the steps you did for pushing policies?